# How to implement fast runtime errors in a virtual machine?

Tags: compiler-construction, runtime, vm-implementation

So I made a basic stack-based virtual machine and a compiler that compiles bytecode for it, but I've run into an issue that I have no idea how to solve.

I need to check for things like dividing by zero and stack overflows and throw runtime errors, but the only way I understand to do this is to use exceptions (I'm doing this in C++), or by writing the ifs myself. But putting ifs all over the place will make the VM **really slow**.

What is the best way to implement runtime errors that ideally uses no CPU until an actual error is thrown?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about *the best*, but in a byte-code interpreter that I wrote I chose to have a `try/catch` around the main switch statement in the interpreter. Yes, that does mean you have an implicit exception frame around every statement, which adds a certain run-time overhead, but this is an interpreter after all, so for me that overhead is bearable.

Comment: Yeah, that's about as far as I got as well. I'm on Windows, so now I'm trying to figure out a combination of SetUnhandledExceptionFilter() and RaiseException() etc., but so far no success.